# How can I get more specific information when profiling javascript in the browser?

Tags: javascript, performance, firefox, profiling

I'm debugging some UI code I wrote and here's the performance report (you can click on this to see a bigger screenshot):

[image: profile report]

To summarize, `drawContainer` is slow, but it's being called recursively and it's not always slow.  The report does not give me any insight into the state that's being passed in so I have no idea which situation makes it slow.

---

You can see it's being called higher on the stack without significant performance issues.  To me that implies that `drawContainer` *can* be slow but it isn't always slow.  I can't figure out how to get any more information from the Firefox profiler than this but I also can't see how to debug the performance issue with so little information.

Is there a technique I can use to figure out what state is being passed into this function **when** it's slow without

1. Majorly interfering with the performance report?  EG: I assume if I put `console.log` everywhere, it would slow down this function a lot and I'd get false positives.
2. Getting information overload?  EG: If I put `console.log` in here it'll print out thousands of lines and only a few of those lines would be relevant.

I don't *need* to solve this in firefox, that's just the browser I'm using.  By that I mean if chrome has better tools for this I'd be willing to switch.

Answer (score 1):

Look at 1) the inclusive % column, and 2) the line numbers.

No function is *slow*, but it may be doing *more work than necessary*.

This shows that `drawComponent` calls `drawContainer` three levels deep before it gets to `drawLabel`.
If any of those calls happens two or more times when it might only be done once, then you can see how that would produce a multiplier effect on the amount of work done.

Also, what you are looking at is called a "hot path".
The problem with hot paths is you could actually have something else that is a big problem, but you don't see it because it is distributed among a number of other paths, each of which is not as "hot" as the one shown, but together are larger.

In particular, I'm curious about the lines that have percentages less than about 70%. Where is the rest of the time going? You can't assume it's ignorable.

That's why I use random pausing. No problem can escape it. I hope there's a way you can pause the browser and examine stack samples.
(The usual objection is there's no way you can take 1000s of manual stack samples.
The usual answer is - look at the percents.
Anything taking 20% you're going to see twice in 10 samples, more or less.
So where does the idea come from that you need 1000s of samples?)

Comment: `Look at 1) the inclusive % column` I'm not sure what you're referring to.  Is that visible in the screenshot?  I do see a % column but I don't know what you mean by "inclusive % column"

Comment: @tieTYT: You can tell it's inclusive because the percents are higher the higher you are in the call stack. It is the percent of stack samples containing that line of code. The top level routine is on every stack sample. Of those, the next line down is the one on the most samples. Of those, the next one is the one on the most samples, and so on. That's the "hot path". But as I said, there are plenty of places off the hot path for elephants to hide.